# Selecting a committee of $5$ out of $20$ with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

A company has $20$ employees, $12$ males and $8$ females.  How many ways are there to form a committee of $5$ employees that contain at least one male and at least one female?

This is what I got: $12\times19\times18\times17\times16-12\times11\times10\times9\times8-8\times7\times6\times5\times4$

Is this correct?

Comment: Presumably the first $12$ is a typo, $20$ is intended. If we fix that, we get the number of **ordered** choices, or equivalently the number of ways to choose a president, vice-president, secretary, treasurer, and fifth wheel. For the number of **committees**, you would have to divide by $5!$. That will give you the right answer. But better, use the approach suggested by Ross Millikan.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to count all the committees, without regard to the restrictions on sex.  Can you do that?  Then subtract the all-female and all-male committees.  Can you count those?